# About my last question of the problem of young experiment

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment

as you can see Ive conducted the young experiment with these tiny tiny holes you can see in the pics but get no result again. why ? I asked and your answer was about the size of slit but these slits are not big so where is the final problem ?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't post followup information as a separate question.

Comment: For the third time: your slits are *too far apart*.  Big doesn't matter as much.  Split your laser by shining it on a staple or a hair.

Comment: @mahsa.e.1378 Take your laser. Shine it on a single piece of hair. You will see an interference pattern. Stop trying to cut holes in cardboard; it won't work.

Comment: no . unfortunetly I didn't see any interference pattern.I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

in order to obtain the wave nature of light you need to make your slits as close to each other as you possibly can as well as make the slits as thin as possible.

The two slits/holes need to be VERY close to each other

I applaud you for taking interest in experimental physics!  Often times experimental physics is a matter of changing all the variables you have available.  In this case change the geometry of the slits :p

I hope this helps.  Sometimes we need several different explanations in order for an idea to click.  Dont get discouraged! Best wishes! :D

If someone out there can translate this answer to Farsi that would be most excellent and most helpful